# Hive Error Parse Exception

Tags: oracle, hive

Tried to extract the the last updated time using below query.

hive is throwing exception Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:7 cannot recognize input near ''cast((cast(sys_extract_utc(update_time) AS DATE) - TO_DATE('' '01' '-' in expression specification (state=42000,code=40000)

```html
select cast(10000 as int),
           case data_type
            when 'TIMESTAMP' then
        concat('     ,cast((cast(sys_extract_utc(update_time) AS DATE) - TO_DATE('01-01-1970 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 86400 AS INT) last_date_time_ts')
            else
              concat('     ,#unknown data_type : ', data_type)
           end
      from (select row_number() over() ln, table_name, column_name, data_type, column_id 
              from test.all_tab_columns
             where date_key in (select max(date_key) from test.all_tab_columns)
               and table_name = 'test_table'
                      ) data
```

Comment: The code looks like Oracle but the error looks like Hive. While there is support for querying a Hive datastore from Oracle, I don't think that is what you are doing. I suggest you explain your overall situation.

Comment: @GaryMyers there is all_tab_columns table in hive. i'm trying to extract the select statement for any table in all_tab_columns by running a script but seems like sys_extract _utc doesn't work in hive